# Change currency symbol based on product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, currency

I am trying to change the default Woocommerce currency symbol based on the product category.

My default WC currency is set to USD and all my products display with `'$'` prefix before the price. But instead of `'$'`, I would like to show `'$$$'` only for the products that are in `'clearance'` category.

This is my code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {

    global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

    if ( has_term( 'clearance', 'product_cat' ) ) {

        switch( $currency ) {
             case 'USD': $currency_symbol = '$$$'; break;
        }
        return $currency_symbol;
    }       
}
```

It works, and '$$$' is displayed only for the products within the 'clearance' category, however it removes the '$' from all products in the remaining categories.

I need that if statement to do nothing if the condition is not met.

I've also tried with `endif` closing tag like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {

    global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

    if ( has_term( 'clearance', 'product_cat' ) ) :

        switch( $currency ) {
             case 'USD': $currency_symbol = '$$$'; break;
        }
        return $currency_symbol;

    endif;      
}
```

but same thing here. It shows `'$$$'` for all products within 'clearance' category, but removes the `'$'` for any other product.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Related: [Custom cart item currency symbol based on product category in Woocommerce 3.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726965/custom-currency-symbol-based-on-product-category-in-all-woocommerce-pages/52729265#52729265)

You need to put `return $currency_symbol;` outside the `if` statement this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
    global $post, $product;

    if ( has_term( 'clearance', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        switch( $currency ) {
             case 'USD': $currency_symbol = '$$$'; 
             break;
        }
    }
    return $currency_symbol; // <== HERE
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a child theme for the current theme can be the solution but I think you don't have to do that much if you only want to change symbol.

Simply go to the woocommerce back end files ..

`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php`

If you don't have back end file excess download file manager in your Wordpress theme you will see these folder in you main site.

`wp-content>>plugins>>woocommerce>>includes>>wc-core-functions.php`

In `wc-core-function.php` file you will see the symbol

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPrOe.png)